# Python 3,4 getattr invalid syntax

Tags: python

I have an array with the different queries I'd like to make

```
month = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar']

monthly_bill = [ getattr(my.path.to, x) for x in month \ if x is not None]
```

However, I'm getting an invalid syntax error

```
*** SyntaxError: Invalid syntax
```

How can I properly access each query using getattr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting a close `]` and removing the `\`.

```
month = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar']

monthly_bill = [ getattr(my.path.to, x) for x in month if x is not None]
```

Comment: Thanks, in my code it was on multiple lines. None types are still getting in, any ideas? thanks

Comment: How would they be `None` if you're defining the list a line above with clearly no `None`s?